# Error:While using cvMinMaxLoc

Tags: opencv

I'm new to the opencv...i want to find the minimum value in the matrix..but i d'not know where i did mistake...please help me...thanks in advance...

```
int main(int argc,char** argv[])
{
    CvMat *mat, mathdr;
    double data[] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 
                      21, 22, 23, 24, 
                      31, 32, 33, 34 };
        ////CvMat* orig = &cvMat( 3, 4, CV_64FC1, data );
    ///mat = cvReshape(orig,&mathdr,1,12);
    ///CvMat* mat2 = cvCreateMat(orig->cols,orig->rows,mat->type);
    ///cvTranspose(orig,mat2);
    double min_val;
    double max_val;
    cvMinMaxLoc(data,&min_val,&max_val);
    printf("Min val %f \n",min_val);
    printf("Max Val %f \n",max_val);
    return 0;
 ///cvDoubleMatPrint(orig);
}
```

Error is...
Unhandled exception at 0x757cd36f in New_opencv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002bed0c..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using the wrong parameter to cvMinMaxLoc. The first parameter should be a const CvArr pointer, and not a float array.

```
cvMinMaxLoc(data,&min_val,&max_val);
```

You should create a matrix or CvArr out of the double array you've declared.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply...But I'm totally new in this open cv.i can get it...Can u give any example for that... it will be very useful for me.

Comment: Sure, it would be something like this:
  float modelPoint[] =  { modelPoints[p].x, modelPoints[p].y, modelPoints[p].z, 1.0f };
        CvMat modelPointMatrix = cvMat( 4, 1, CV_32F, modelPoint );
just like your commented line on CvMat *orig.